# DELETE Data from MYSQL older than X days with Unix time in miliseconds

Tags: mysql, sql, time, unix-timestamp

I want to delete all the rows with timestamp older than 180 days from a specific table in my database.

I've tried the this:

```
DELETE FROM on_search 
WHERE time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY));
```

but time is in 13 digit unix format like 1543821263977

Comment: Multiply it by 1000 and you will have time in miliseconds as of `time` col     `WHERE time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))*1000`

Answer (score 2):

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

Returns time in seconds.

You will have to multiply it by 1000 to make it 13 digit(time in miliseconds).

```
DELETE FROM on_search 
WHERE time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(3), INTERVAL 30 DAY))*1000;
```

Comment: now i have used this :
DELETE FROM on_search 
WHERE time < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(3), INTERVAL 30 DAY))*1000;